# select not display correctly after change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find any solution to simple value change in select, code works corretly in Chrome and in IE but doesn't work in FF

```
    <select id='testsel' name='test'>
      <option value="">-- select something --</option>
      <option value="1">selected</option>
    </select>
```

and if I try

```
    $('#testsel').val("1");
```

value is selected but not displayed (you can see if you expand select). What is strange

```
    $('#testsel').val();
```

returns "" (first value)

Same problem if I try

```
    $('#testsel > option[value="1"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

but this time result is bit different

```
    $('#testsel > option[value="1"]').attr("selected");
```

I see "selected" as a result, but on screen nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: Hmm... It works good on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4WWe/

Comment: +1 Yep, works fine for me as well. Firefox 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some styling plugin for the select ?

Usually those plugins will replace the element, and altering the values through code will not reflect on the replaced element. (*although i find it strange that it does work on other browsers*)

For normal elements your example code should work (*as verified in the comments*).

Comment: I found cause of the problem, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work in FF

        $('select', form).not(exclude).children('option').removeAttr('selected');

After commenting out everything works.

Comment: @pma_, if you could provide a link or a jsfiddle.net which shows the problem in action it would be great help as we need to see what is in `exclude` what is in `form` etc.. to debug properly..